# What is the proper way to offer a class as a service to save data?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework on an IIS server. My service has several methods that are accessible to authenticated users.

Here is an example of one of the methods:

```
public bool SaveTruckInventoryReading(TruckInventory truckInventory)
{
  entities.AddToTruckInventories(truckInventory);
  entities.SaveChanges();
  return true;
}
```

I didn't put much information in it since I wanted to ask a specific question. TruckInventory is an Entity Object. Should I create a class that they pass in or is what I'm doing the proper way to allow them to pass the object into my method?

If I create a class, I have to convert it over to my Entity Object. Which to me, seems like extra code that isn't necessary.

Is exposing my entity object, as shown above, a bad way of accepting the information or should I have them pass in a generic class?

Comment: I would create a repository that consumes the TruckInventory and inherits from a base repository that has methods like Add, Delete, Edit etc. This way your model will be internal to the repository and may be an interface from your repository will be exposed.

Comment: Is TruckInventory POCO?

Comment: @Maess yes it is, if I understand POCO correctly. It's a very basic string based object.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany isn't that overkill? I just need to save 1 record.

Comment: While I agree that you should most likely create a unit of work and repositories, that is not the question you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'right' answer to this.

If `TruckInventory` is POCO, then there is no great harm in exposing it in the way you are.  However, there are many that would argue that this may violate your separation of concerns.

If separation of concerns is an issue, then I would go with a `TuckInventory` DTO that exposes only the information you want the consumers to have access to.  If you go this route, you will need a mapper like AutoMapper to map from your DTO to your Entity.

Comment: Seperation of concerns <-- good point. I'll do just that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be a good idea to directly expose your entity in this way. You should create a DTO and pass that to service and then convert DTO to entity and save it in DB.

Reason is that the EF classes aren't designed for serialization. They would have lot of extra information which you won't need to send to server